# What are some authoritative Vietnamese Dictionaries? …and how do they disambiguate the two pronunciations of <gia>?

Tags: phonology, dictionary, vietnamese

What are some authoritative Vietnamese dictionaries? …and how do they disambiguate the two pronunciations of `<gia>`? (Something with an English or Chinese gloss is preferred.)

[Wikipedia on the Vietnamese Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vietnamese_alphabet&oldid=782718424#Consonants) has this to say about `<gia>`:

> This causes some ambiguity with the diphthong *ia*/*iê*, for example *gia* could be either *gi*+*a* [za ~ ja] or *gi*+*ia* [ziə̯ ~ jiə̯]. If there is a tone mark the ambiguity is resolved: *giá* is *gi*+*á* and *gía* is *gi*+*ía*.